# Sending photo from URL with Telegram Bot - php

Tags: telegram-bot

Excuse me because I can't write english well.
When I send a link to telegram, telegram automatically shows the link.
For example when I send this:
http://bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/LaurelMoss_EN-AU9551903343_1366x768.jpg
in telegram you can see the picture.
This image link will be expired.
How I can't send a picture link to telegram, and make the telegram to grab it and save it on it's servers. Then show the image without link?
And I can not leech the image on my server. (my server is week)
I use this class to send a link to telegram:

```
<?php
include("Telegram.php");

$telegram = new Telegram('my_token');


$content = array('chat_id' => '@my_Channel', 'text' => 'http://bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/LaurelMoss_EN-AU9551903343_1366x768.jpg');
$telegram->sendMessage($content);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to upload photo to bot API is to send there image's content. That's why anyway you have to download image to your server. But you could delete it as soon as API request finished. Or even not to save image at all:

> $telegram->sendPhoto(['chat_id' => '@my_Channel', 'photo' =>
>   file_get_contents('URL')]);

Here is an example from library you use https://github.com/Eleirbag89/TelegramBotPHP/:

```
// Load a local file to upload. If is already on Telegram's Servers just pass the resource id
$img = curl_file_create('test.png','image/png');
$content = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'photo' => $img );
$telegram->sendPhoto($content);
```

`

Comment: hi.
Somebody give me another answer?

Comment: this answer is correct, could you please tell us why you need another solution ? This is the way to go